# Neo4j recursive query with various relationship sense

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Considering this graph structure:

[image]

I would like to run a recursive cypher query to get all the nodes starting from the yellow one.

As you can see relationships are in different sense, but have an attribute defined. Let say for the descending relationship the attribute is impact=dtos (destination to source), and for the others impact = stod

I would like to go through relationships independently of the sense but checking the impact attribute. Somethink like

```
()-[r *1..]->() where r.impact=dtos OR ()<-[r *1..]-() where r.impact=stod
```

Is it possible to do something like this or should I create another relationship in the opposite sense ?

I hope I'm clear enough

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
MATCH p=(a:Yellow)-[r*]-(end)
WHERE   all(rel IN RELS(p) WHERE rel.impact="dtos" or rel.impact="stod")
RETURN p
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but if I'm not wrong this will go through all relationships independently of the sense ? I mean this graph shown in the picture is part of a much bigger graph so I'm afraid doing that it will retrieve all the graph (more than 100 000 nodes). What I would like to select as relationship is "rel going out and impact = dtos or rel going in and impact = stod".  Maybe it's too complex doing this way ?